# Fill down from a variable starting row

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure how to fill down from a variable row. For example sometimes it starts at 40000 sometimes it starts at 50000.

This is what it looks like right now

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A40958:A43550")
Range("A40958:A43550").Select
```

I know how to fill down to the last row but I'm not sure how to get the first number to be variable as well.
In the A column I go to the last cell and then fill down. How do I express that?

Comment: Can you add a language tag?

Answer (score 4):

Scrap `.AutoFill` and use the [Range.FillDown Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) by defining the begin and end boundaries of the range just as if you selected the cells and tapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

```
dim rw as long
rw = 40000
with activesheet
    .range("A" & rw, "A" & .cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).row).FillDown
end with
```

That will fill down A from row 40000 to the extents (last used cell) of column B.